# Как сделать так, чтобы команда выводила сообщение человека, которое он написал?

Tags: discord.py

Пример:

Человек пишет команду **!8ball Я хороший?**, мне нужно чтобы после написания этой команды вывелось: **Вопрос: Я хороший?**

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def 8ball(ctx, *, args):
    await ctx.send(f"Вопрос: {args}")
```

cogs:

```
@commands.command()
async def 8ball(self, ctx, *, args):
    await ctx.send(f"Вопрос: {args}")
```

`!8ball Я хороший?` - Вывод `Вопрос: Я хороший?`